# How to retry failed update requests(412 error code) in azure table storage operations?

Tags: azure, concurrency

I am looking for a solution to handle the update failures in azure table operations due to error code 412.My application will make concurrent update requests to the table and most of the time it fails with code 412.At that time I need to retry the request and make it right.
The type of updates are like, each request will read the data and union it with new data and place it back.The challenge is, my application need to handle large amount of requests like this in fraction of seconds

Comment: Most likely your request is failing with this error because of Etag mismatch. Please share the code and also tell us why multiple clients (processes) need to update a single entity.

Comment: Actually there are no multiple clients.Our application is a map providing service which plot maps by fetching lot of map tiles.So while fetching each tile,we need to update the boundary of plotted map by doing union of each tile boundary.so lot of tiles being plotted at the same time and each of the tile will try to update the boundary

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri, I have updated the comment could you check?

Comment: Hmmm....interesting problem! So if I understand correctly, your map boundary is an entity in Azure Storage table. You fetch these tiles through some asynchronous parallel process and as and when the tiles are fetched, you get the map boundary from storage, update it based on the tile data and then save it back. This update is conditional (by enforcing Etag) however since many tiles are trying to update the same boundary, you're getting this 412 error. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes you are absolutely right

Comment: @GauravMantri
One more update, we are reading the same entity and trying to update that and we are keeping the entity based on sessionid

Comment: Not knowing much about your application, I am curious to know why you need to update the boundary whenever a tile information is received. Can't you just wait for all the information to come and then update the map boundary?

Comment: @GauravMantri Because each tile need to be charged

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe using azure table storage I do not think there is any other way than what you are doing already. So either update the ETag and resend the request or else unconditionally overwrite what is there which will cause you lose updates.

In your case I would also experiment with Azure Document Db so you could in theory push that union logic to the server side as a stored procedure which could transparently do the retry on ETag failure. That should be much faster because you would not need to do any I/O request for retries from client side and assume whatever you get back from the db is the latest and the most up to date Boundary entity.

Comment: we are using azure table service and not sure how to use stored procedures on that

Comment: Yep like I mentioned in the answer options for azure table storage is limited and do not include stored procs hence the suggestion to investigate leveraging other storage options ie document db that support server side scripting.

Comment: Thanks @doguarslan, as of now we are going with some retry logic because we cannot change our storage system at the moment